# How write join with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Here is my select in SQL:

```
select * 
from FactorItems fi 
inner join tblparts p on p.PartsID = fi.PartRef
```

So as I use `*` to get all columns from my join.

But with this code:

```
var FactorItem = (from FI in context.FactorItems
                  join P in context.tblparts on FI.PartRef equals P.PartsID
                  where (FI.FactorRef == FactorID) 
                  select FI);
```

I just get data which is in `FI`. I want to get all data - so what code do I need for that?

Comment: Check the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that Linq to Sql code, you can return all data creating a new object:

```
var FactorItem = (from FI in context.FactorItems
                                  join P in context.tblparts on FI.PartRef equals P.PartsID
                                  where (FI.FactorRef == FactorID) 
                                  select new {FI,P};
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning only one entity,  `FI`. You need to return both the entities .. `FI` and `P` , like :

```
// your rest of query
select new { FI, P}
```

This way it should get you all the concerned data